# Sumifs criteria to look for the value in two columns

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

hi i am using sumifs function "=SUMIFS('AT&TT'!$F:$F,'AT&TT'!$C:$C,AT!$C$3,'AT&TT'!$E:$E,AT!$E$3,'AT&TT'!$H:$H,AT!G2)"
which is working fine, but additionally what I require is in first criteria of the formula

"=SUMIFS('AT&TT'!$F:$F,***'AT&TT'!$C:$C,AT!$C$3***,'AT&TT'!$E:$E,AT!$E$3,'AT&TT'!$H:$H,AT!G2)"
instead of column range AT&TT'!$C:$C I need AT&TT'!$C:$D, i want to look for the value in either of the columns.

I tried using vlookup as criteria inside sumifs.

Answer (score 0):

So what about the simple method:

```
=SUMIFS('AT&TT'!$F:$F,'AT&TT'!$C:$C,AT!$C$3,'AT&TT'!$E:$E,AT!$E$3,'AT&TT'!$H:$H,AT!G2)+"=SUMIFS('AT&TT'!$F:$F,'AT&TT'!$D:$D,AT!$C$3,'AT&TT'!$E:$E,AT!$E$3,'AT&TT'!$H:$H,AT!G2)"
```

Where you do 1 sumifs for Range C and another for Range D .